# Why does the same eight-character hexadecimal code show a different color in different software?

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

I want to pick up the color *#FFEAF0FF* from the [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) color scheme to [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code):

> [image: Screenshot of three colour swatches with hexadecimal colour codes; the one mentioned shows as light blue]

But when I put this hexadecimal code into Visual Studio Code, it becomes a different color:

> [image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code configuration showing light pink]

They are totally different colors (light blue vs light pink), so how can I make *#FFEAF0FF* display the right color in the six-digit format?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Strip off the leading FF.

Wherever you got that 8-hex-digit color from (an Android app, I'm guessing?), appears to be using an "ARGB" color scheme, where the first pair of hex digits represents the "alpha channel" (basically the opacity value).

Traditional web hex colors just use 6-hex-digit RGB, but about 4 years ago, browsers started supporting 8-hex-digit color codes in the "RGBA" format. Unlike Android's "ARGB", the emerging web standard's use of the "RGBA" format puts the alpha channel in the more compatible place at the trailing end of the color code (I'm not sure why Android chose ARGB instead of RGBA). 8-hex-digit RGBA web color codes are in the process of being standardized as part of "CSS Color Module, Level 4".

Comment: Great answer! This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909935/117259) basically states the same, but with a few more details.

Comment: 8-hex-digit is also valid web color (CSS), but it's RRGGBBAA.

Comment: The trailing `FF` is the issue, as the alpha channel affects transparency only, not hues: `EAF0FF` is light blue [R:234 G: 240 B:255], whereas `FFEAF0` is light pink [R:255 G:234 B:240]. 
 All OSes have programs that use an 8-digit hex - Windows uses it in the Registry, Stardock  Windowblinds uses it, Photoshop programs use it, etc. If a program/OS supports transparency and uses hex for its RGB, it's likely going to use hex for the alpha channel as well.

Comment: @JW0914 You got it backwards. OP wanted light blue, but got pink, because he was coming from a tool that used ARGB, and going to a tool that used RGB[A]. The leading FF was the issue, not the trailing one.

Comment: Note that #RGBA started out being supported by most graphic editing tools long before browsers supported it. Browsers implemented #RGBA because it was the de-facto standard

Comment: #AARRGGBB makes some sense in that you can just parse the digits as a 32-bit number, and then only look at the low three bytes / low 24 bits to get the RGB values. The RGB values end up in the same bit positions as with just #RRGGBB. With the options being #RRGGBBAA and #RRGGBB, the low byte would be BB in one and AA in the other. (Though I guess it would make more sense if AA=00  would be normal non-transparent color instead of the other way around. Then you could just treat #RRGGBB the same as #00RRGGBB even more all the way. Well, I probably miss something, but anyway.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Interesting hypothesis, but doesn't it assume big-endian? All the dominant platforms today are little-endian.

Comment: @Spiff, um, no. I can't see how endianness would come into it. It doesn't matter which order you put the bytes in, just that you know where to find the least-significant byte (or three).

Comment: @ilkkachu: They're equivalent; you just have to do some simple bit-shifting and/or masking to convert the one into the other. Neither is particularly more efficient than the other.